# Silverlight 4 superscript in RichTextBox in Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, richtextbox

in WPF superscript is:

```
        var currentAlignment = richTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.BaselineAlignmentProperty);
        BaselineAlignment newAlignment = ((BaselineAlignment)currentAlignment == BaselineAlignment.Superscript) ? BaselineAlignment.Baseline : BaselineAlignment.Superscript;
        richTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.BaselineAlignmentProperty, newAlignment);
        richTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.FontSizeProperty, (double)8);
```

But how to implement Inline.BaselineAlignmentProperty in Web Application ?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight does not support BaseLineAlignment, however you could achieve superscript by using Unicode, just put the following in your code-behind and it will do the trick.

```
    string superscript = string.Empty;
    switch (SerialNo)
    {
        case 1:
            superscript = "\x00B9";
            break;
        case 2:
            superscript = "\x00B2";
            break;
        case 3:
            superscript = "\x00B3";
            break;
        case 4:
            superscript = "\x2074";
            break;
        case 5:
            superscript = "\x2075";
            break;
        case 6:
            superscript = "\x2076";
            break;
        case 7:
            superscript = "\x2077";
            break;
        case 8:
            superscript = "\x2078";
            break;
        case 9:
            superscript = "\x2079";
            break;
        default:
            superscript = "\x2070";
            break;
    }
    label.Content += superscript;
```